# How to restrict Angular2 routing parameters?

Tags: angular, routes

Given this simple routing example I'd like to be able to restrict the `:page` argument.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':page', component: PageFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Preferably with an Array of Strings. Expected behaviour here is to check the `:page` to be one of the Array elements and route to the `PageNotFoundComponent` if it is not there.

```
// pseudo code
let knownPages = ["welcome", "shop", "about"];
(...)
{ path: ':page@knownPages', component: PageFoundComponent }
```

The concept is borrowed from Symfony2 routing mechanism.

How should I approach it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `UrlMatcher` that was introduced recently

```
{ path: ':page', component: PageFoundComponent, matcher: ... },
```

but I haven't found any docs about it yet.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use Router [Guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards). In specific, likely the [CanActivate Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html).

```js
import { AuthGuard }                from '../auth-guard.service';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':page',
    component: Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

Note that you can use multiple guards. One could return true if the path is in an array, one could be related to authentication, one could be related to roles, etc.